# saml or Oauth2 authentication streamlit

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml, streamlit

I have a streamlit app deployed using kubernetes. I can reach my app through an url : https://my-app.my-domain.net

I would like to use our okta portal to auhtenticate the access to the app, what do we have to develop to make it work?

Comment: Do you have a good reason for preferring SAML over OAuth2?

Comment: thank you to ask @Dai, we could use OAuth2 too